# Jackson custom serializer or value object?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm returning to backend development after a few years focusing on iOS. I've chosen Spring Boot with Kotlin.

- I would like to have a domain-centric, general, reusable model objects.
- For service invocations I would like to return use-cases specific responses where the payload in/out is just the information for that particular scenario. (We can call this "contract-first" or "don't spill your guts")

In the past I might've implemented a service by mapping the information from reusable model objects onto a serializable value object using a framework like [Dozer](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer).

Alternatively, I was thinking of registering a custom serializer for a given endpoint, as eg Django Rest Framework does. (Not sure how this would work given jackson serializes by annotations).

**Questions:**

- Is there an easy way to use custom serializers with jackson to do what I want?
- Or is it better to continue using the value-object approach I used years ago?

Comment: I would say this question should be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ luboskrnac Of the two questions in the bullet points, I think the first one is a SO type question. Perhaps I can move the second one to StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case, using dedicated DTOs could be a good idea. Just so you know, you can get more flexibility from Jackson without implementing custom serializers for each scenario - [Jackson Json Views are now supported in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#json-views) and quite useful.